# CountDownTimer onTick

Tags: java, android, audio, countdowntimer

I'm using a CountDownTimer. I'd like to play a sound at specific time just for advise . Well here is my code:

```
@Override
        public void onTick(long l) {


            if((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l))) == 10){
                 reproducirAviso();
            }

            tiempo.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l))));

        }
```

What is happening? The method "reproducirAviso()" is called several times and the sound is played choppy... 
What can I do to solve this problem?
Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to have reproducirAviso() not to be called several times add a flag to check if already running reproducirAviso().

For example, somewhere set a static boolean like

```
public static boolean reproducing = false;

public void reproducirAviso()
{ 
    //
    // lots of your code
    // 
    reproducing = false;    
}
```

so your code becomes

```
@Override
public void onTick(long l) 
{ 
    if(!reproducing && (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l))) == 10){
         reproducirAviso();
    }

    tiempo.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l))));

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer but I already thought on that solution with no luck!

Comment: First of all I have to say I'm using Genymotion and I discovered that some sounds are not well played. That's the reason I can't discard your option. I'd like to try it in a real device and check if the problem is Genymotion.

Comment: After trying in a real device, it worked as expected, so I have to say that Genymotion has a problem playing somo type of sounds... So many thanks for the hint!